# JqGrid editrules number true does not work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to prevent letters from being saved to a numeric field in jqgrid, I'm using inlineEditing in jqGrid.

I can check if the field was filled with the property

```
editrules : {required: true}
```

Following the documentation I put the property "number: true"

```
editrules : {required: true, number: true}
```

But it doesn't work. My jqGrid version is 4.5.4, my colModel is below

```
colModel : [
    {formatter:"integer",index:"PK_FACTIVEL",search:true,hidden:false,sorttype:"integer",sortable:true,width:10,align:"right",name:"PK_FACTIVEL",editrules:{number:true,required:true},editable:true},
....
]
```

Comment: What does not work? Any demo with test case is appreciated. This [demo](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/formatter_telefone/)  uses the same settings and work as expected.

Comment: I discovered the problem. my colModel is generated from information saved in the database, the property "editrules : {number: true}" comes from a JSON and was "editrules" : {"number ": "true"}, this space was causing me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem.

My colModel is generated from information saved in the database,

The property "editrules : {number: true}" comes from a JSON

and was "editrules" : {"number ": "true"},

this space was causing me problems. Thanks Tommy for help!!!